TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor . I am getting this error when using IenAIApi with nodejs
I am trying to use OpenAi's function calling. I have installed Axios, dotenv and OpenAi packeges like
 npm install openai@latest

 npm i axios

 npm i dotenv

When I am trying to create configuration with OpenAi api key, It returns the error like, "TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor"
MY code is
require('dotenv').config();

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

I want to implement function calling

This question is similar to: OpenAI API error: "Configuration is not a constructor". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
